# Implementing a "Like" button. Breaking CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't believe how HARD to implement this bloody button has become!

Perhaps it works at the moment, but the comment box craps all over the page layout.

http://www.addinall.net

The comment box extends the length of the #container, leaves it empty when it goes away, and throws the header into another dimension.

I have this crap now living in my index.html(php)

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">


  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="249303871912490" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.addinall.net" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="That's IT - Mark Addinall" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="http://www.addinall.net/mylogo.jpg" /> 

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

AND in my footer

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.addinall.net" data-width="100" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

I tried reverting back to the iFrame implementation, but that breaks HTML5 validation.  ARRRGGGHHHH!!

Any ideas before I chuck it and forget I ever heard of Facebook?

Comment: `overflow: visible` applied to your `#container` element could be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Thank you.  That stopped it breaking my CSS at least.  It throws the comment box mostly off screen.

It needs:

data-commentgrow="[up|down]"
data-comment="[on|off]"
data-buttoncolour="[white|yellow|...|black]"

At the very least.

Mark Addinall.

Comment: maybe you could move that button at the begin of your main content

Comment: I have the impression that you're constantly updating your page and that we're after a moving target here. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something? At least then we're talking about something constant. Also, how does "reverting back to the iFrame implementation" break HTML5 validation? Unless you're doing it wrong, `iframe` is a valid element in HTML5.